# SSRS parenthesis around negative values

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I have expression like this

```
=Sum(Fields!TotalBatch.Value - Fields!TotalUsage.Value)
```

I need a format like below

123.34

(234.45)

I had already set the properties > Number > Use Separator (,) > decimal places = 0 > Negative Numbers using brackets (12,5). But why the separator and the brackets still not appear in when I made preview ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this in the textbox:

```
=Format(Sum(Fields!TotalBatch.Value - Fields!TotalUsage.Value),"##0.00;(##0.00)")
```

Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Alejandro,

```
=Format(Sum(Fields!TotalBatch.Value - Fields!TotalUsage.Value),"##0,0;(##0,0)")
```

it's work on me finally.. thank you :)